# Terminal can't execute commands

Tags: release-hera

after I installed MS SQL and Flutter, on my freshly installed Elementary OS, and after the installations, I can't run any commands on my terminal.
[image]

It happens with every command I try to execute such as "apt update", "cd" etc. I added some paths to my .bashrc file for Flutter and MS SQL but now i can't remove them, What can i do to fix it?